# C++ Error C4091 when inheritance nested Class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hi all I am new in here and I got a error when declaring a constructor in nested class.

lets say I have a class named Event, there are 2 nested class that inherit it, SampleEvent and TimeEvent, in SampleEvent and TimeEvent constructor, there are a error.

Here is my code:

```
// Event Class
#ifndef EVENT_H
#define EVENT_H

#include <iostream>

namespace Engine
{
    namespace Data
    {
        class Event
        {
            public:
                // Class Variable
                int Measure;
                int Beat;
                int Position;

                // This Class that was I mean
                class SampleEvent;
                class TimeEvent;

                // Constructor
                Event(int measure, int beat, int pos);
        };

        // Sample Event Class
        class Event::SampleEvent : public Event
        {
            public:
            // variable in SampleEvent Class
            int ID;
            float Pan;
            float Vol;

            // Constructor
            SampleEvent(int id, float pan, float vol, int measure, int beat, int pos);
        };

        // Time Event Class
        class Event::TimeEvent : public Event
        {
            public:
            // variable in TimeEvent Class
            double Value;

            // Constructor
            TimeEvent(double value, int measure, int beat, int pos);
        };

        // Constructor of Event
        Event::Event(int measure, int beat, int pos)
        {
            Measure         = measure;
            Beat            = beat;
            Position        = pos;
        }

        // Constructor of Sample Event
        Event::SampleEvent::SampleEvent(int id, float pan, float vol, int measure, int beat, int pos) : Event::Event(measure, beat, pos)
        {
            ID                      = id;
            Pan                     = pan;
            Vol                     = vol;
            Measure         = measure;
            Beat            = beat;
            Position        = pos;
        }

        // Constructor of Time Event
        Event::TimeEvent::TimeEvent(double value, int measure, int beat, int pos) : Event::Event(measure, beat, pos)
        {
            Value                   = value;
            Measure         = measure;
            Beat            = beat;
            Position        = pos;
        }
    }      
}
#endif
```

This give me 2 error:

```
Error C2039: '{ctor}' : is not a member of 'Engine::Data::Event' (line 60)
Error C2039: '{ctor}' : is not a member of 'Engine::Data::Event' (line 71)
```

Can Someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int Position` is missing a semicolon.

Also, you are missing a closing bracket at the end of the code:

```
        }      
    } // <--- MISSING
}
```

But, the main problem with the code, is that you need to explicitly initialize your base class constructors because the default constructors are not implicitly defined (and cannot be used) since you defined a constructor `Event(int measure, int beat, int pos);`.

```
Event::SampleEvent::SampleEvent(int id, float pan, float vol, 
                               int measure, int beat, int pos)
: Event(id, id, id) // This is just an example, pass the proper values here
{
   //...
}

Event::TimeEvent::TimeEvent(double value, int measure, int beat, int pos)
: Event(measure, measure, measure) // Pass the proper values to base ctor
```

**EDIT**

Now the error is because you used `Event::Event(measure, beat, pos)` instead of `Event`. (However, I think that `Event::Event` *should* work, I think it is a bug in MSVC for not accepting the code.)

Comment: Thanks for reply, look the post, I already edit the code, but still get same error

Comment: @ChronoCross: Change `Event::Event` to `Event`.